# Click outside the div get hide in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When We click outside the div or in a window the xyz should get hide

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);  
   app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {  
        $scope.showDropdown = false;
     $scope.helloClick = function(){
        if($scope.showDropdown == true){
            $scope.showDropdown = false;
        }
        else{
            $scope.showDropdown = true;
        }
     }
  });
```

here is my jsfiddler link
https://jsfiddle.net/8ftrnenw/

Comment: Hi sravan can u help me to resolve the issue

Answer (score 2):

Here is your required solution,

- I created a **`custom directive`**
- That directive takes the **`click-outside`** attribute and it checks for the click on an element where we added that directive.
- If the container is outside the **`element`** on which we added the directive, it hides that **`div`**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.showDropdown = false;
   $scope.hide = function(){
     $scope.showDropdown = false;
   }
   $scope.helloClick = function(){
   $scope.showDropdown = !$scope.showDropdown;
  }
}

});
app.directive('clickOutside', function ($document) {

        return {
           restrict: 'A',
           scope: {
               clickOutside: '&'
           },
           link: function (scope, el, attr) {

               $document.on('click', function (e) {
                   if (el !== e.target && !el[0].contains(e.target)) {
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            scope.$eval(scope.clickOutside);
                        });
                    }
               });
           }
        }

    });
```

```css
.xyz{
 border:1px solid red;
 width:200px;
 height:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div  click-outside="hide()">
<div class="hello" ng-click ="helloClick()">hello</div>
<div class="xyz"  ng-if="showDropdown">xyz</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Please run the above snippet**

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/qpez3hnw/)

**Ps: Explanation if directive:**

`el !== e.target && !el[0].contains(e.target)`

There e is the element you clicked and el is the element on which you added the directive. So it checks if the element you clicked is that directive. If not, then it will hide the required div

`scope.$eval(scope.clickOutside);`

This will evaluate the attribute and calls the function which we gave in `click-outside="hide()"`

Comment: `helloClick` function can be simplified to `$scope.showDropdown = !$scope.showDropdown;`

Comment: Thanks sravan its resolved my issue.Need small help can u plz explain me "if (el !== e.target && !el[0].contains(e.target)) {" this line of code

Comment: there `e` is the `element` you clicked and `el` is the `element` `on` which you added the `directive`. So it checks if the `element` you clicked is that directive. If not, then it will hide the required `div`

Comment: @ASHU, added explanation, please check

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Sravan response. I have added an improvement to only launch this event when target component have been showed.

```
app.directive('clickOutside', function ($document) {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        clickOutside: '&',
        launchEvent: '='
  },
  link: function (scope, el, attr) {

    var launched = false;

    scope.$watch('launchEvent', function (newVal) {

      if (newVal && !launched) {

        launched = true;

        $document.on('click', function (e) {
          if (el !== e.target && !el[0].contains(e.target)) {
            scope.$apply(function () {
              scope.$eval(scope.clickOutside);
            });
          }
        });
      } else {
        launched = false;
        $document.off('click');
      }

    });
  }
}
```

});